# Load remote JSON periodically (error: Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

Tags: javascript, json, macos, apache

I want to periodically load a .json file containing some info, this is **the code** I came up with:

```
var updateIBEX35 = function () {
    var ibexText = document.getElementById("IBEX");

    let url = 'https://www2.ecobolsa.com/js/data/i35.json';
    fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then((out) => {
        alert(out[0].p); // just for 'debug'
    }) .catch(err => alert(err));
}

var intervalID = setInterval(updateIBEX35, 1000);
// clearInterval(intervalID);
```

And this is **the error** I get:

```
[Error] Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (i35.json, line 0)
[Error] Fetch API cannot load https://www2.ecobolsa.com/js/data/i35.json. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

BTW I'm using macOS Sierra with Apache, **I tried to** modify the "httpd.conf" or the user file (/etc/apache2/users/Daniel.conf) by adding somewhere:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

But it didn't work :(

Comment: do you control the `www2.ecobolsa.com` domain?

Comment: Nope, I don't, I'm just trying to access the content of that file

Comment: Then as noted below you will need to use a proxy on server you do control or a third party proxy service

Answer (score 2):

Nothing's going to happen if you change the config at your end. The endpoint you are trying to call doesn't allow the cross-origin request.

Either store the data in a local JSON file and load or contact the site administrator to allow CORS request.

Comment: Another option is creating an endpoint on the samedomain that acts as a proxy and downloads the json server-side.

Comment: Or that ^^^^^^^

Comment: There are also third party proxy services

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are using Apache, if you are also serving PHP pages then why not create a "proxy" that fetchs JSON then serves it from the same domain again? That would solve your cross-origin issue altogether.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo file_get_contents('https://www2.ecobolsa.com/js/data/i35.json');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, I managed to solve my problem **using jQuery** and php:

The **js** file:

```
var url = 'https://www2.ecobolsa.com/js/data/i35.json';

var updateIBEX35 = function () {
    $.post('php/decodeJSON.php', { url: url }, function(data) {
        $("#IBEX").text(data);        
    });
}

setInterval(updateIBEX35, 10000);
```

The decodeJSON.**php** file:

```
<?php
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    echo 'IBEX35: '.json_decode(file_get_contents($url))->{0}->{p};
?>
```